# Deafult behaviour in FORM doesn't work in Angular2

Tags: html, forms, angular

In my HTML I've added the following:

```
<div>
 <form action="https://ssl.somepage.pl/t2/" method="post"
 id="form">
 <input name="api_version" value="dev" type="hidden"/>
 <input name="id" value="123456" type="hidden"/>
 <input name="amount" value="320.00" type="hidden"/>
 <input name="currency" value="PLN" type="hidden"/>
 <input name="description" value="Płatność
 za zamówienie 12345/2014" type="hidden"/>
 <input name="control" value="202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70" type="hidden"/>
 <input name="channel" value="248" type="hidden"/>
 <input name="ch_lock" value="1" type="hidden"/>
 <input name="firstname" value="John" type="hidden"/>
 <input name="lastname" value="Smith" type="hidden"/>
 <input name="email" value="john.smith@example.com" type="hidden"/>
 <input name="type" value="0" type="hidden"/>
 <input name="credit_card_store" value="1" type="hidden"/>
 <input name="credit_card_customer_id" value="f9c6a4-25473-035b58-9daa"
 type="hidden"/>
 <input name="chk"
 value="11ac1938ac47ddd53815b4aeb6230ab9fe4554d82ee11e39c41b9055f38f5c08"
 type="hidden"/>
 </form>
 <p>
 <button type="submit" form="form"
 value="Submit">Pay</button>
 </p>
</div>
```

Which, as I understand, should make post method, and open a new webpage.

However, nothing happens. Any idea why? I am using Angular2.

Comment: Try using `GET`. It works for me.

Comment: @Zange-chan, actually it didn't helped me - in network, there is nothing happening. Could you show plnkr?

Comment: Your `submit` must be inside the `<form>`. And try going to your browser's Developer Tools, and navigate to the Network tab.

Comment: @Zange-chan: nope it must not. Made the same mistake but his method (form=) is also in the specs

Answer (score 1):

The submit button must be inside of the form tag.(Oops sorry didnt know that your method is also possible)

Comment: It didn't change anything

Comment: Try changing id="form" to id="form1". That may cause problems

Answer (score 1):

Try making it like these:

```html
<div>
  <form id="form" method="POST" action="your link">
    . . . . .
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Pay">
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It works fine! Thanks, however, the issue was caused by angular2 form changes

Answer (score 0):

The code is perfectly fine. I did cross verify it. I found the problem with the link you have put in the action attribute. I think the page doesn't exist or there is a problem with page. I added 'https://www.facebook.com' into the action attribute and it got redirected perfectly. So just check the link you have put.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by Angular2 Form changes. To enable default behaviour, I needed to add:

```
 <form ngNoForm ... >
```

To allow normal behaviour